# How do I correctly capture data from a Symbol LS2208 barcode scanner with java

Tags: java

I have been asked to develop a java desktop swing application that reads barcodes and processes data based on products with the relevant barcode.

The barcode scanner we're using is a Symbol LS2208 usb scanner and when it came there was no instructions or cd in the box. We plugged it in, it beeped at us and were able to scan barcode values into notepad as a test.

In my application, how do I ensure that the scanner populates data into the relevant textbox and how do I know when the entire barcode has been scanned? 
Or how to get barcode Scannar input in my application?

Comment: Its very hard to answer this question without see the code .

Comment: actually i want to get data from scanner in my application just... sir if you have any idea about this please guide me. Still i have no code .. but going to code this senario

Comment: Have you tried contacting the manufacturer for information on any interfaces, sdks or the like? Scanning to notepad sounds as if the driver can call some application and input the barcode to it - is that right?

Comment: yes scanner write information on notepad after scanning... but this information is required to me in my application.

Comment: For connecting scanner or any other device needs API @Fildor asking for that.

Comment: Subodh Joshi i have no idea about any api for scanner. i have symbol Scanner LS2208-SR20007R-UR . if have any idea about this please share with me.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/jj126202(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: thanks Fildor and  Subodh Joshi

Answer (score 1):

James already answered most of your questions. This question is already a little bit old, but this might serve people with the same question in the future.

When you connect your scanner through USB, in particular the Zebra scanner (Symbol is part of Zebra Technologies nowadays), it will typically be recognized as a USB HID device by default. See the link Fildor shared for more information on HID Emulation.

So each time you scan the barcode scanner will translate the encoded information as keystrokes since it's emulating a keyboard.
If there is a text field in your application in which you can type, it should also be possible for you to scan into it.

For more information, please see [this portal](https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Mobile+Networks+RFID+and+BarCode+Scanners/Bar+Code+Scanning/General+Purpose+Scanners/LS2208_US-EN) for the PRG (product reference guide).

For Zebra's configuration utility, [123Scan²](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/software/scanning-systems/scanner-drivers-and-utiltities/123scan2-configuration-utility.html). With the latter you can set the scanner to send a suffix or a prefix, such as *Enter* or *Tab*.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with your scanner via System.in if you connect it to USB. Also you can use USB-COM emulator and work with it as you work with com-port. More information here

http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Writing_%22Hello_World%22_to_a_USB_to_serial_converter

Answer (score 0):

This type of scanner is a "Human Interface Device," also known as an HID. This type of scanner can provide input to software anywhere a keyboard can be used to provide input.

> In my application, how do I ensure that the scanner populates data
> into the relevant textbox?

- Your application would not normally be responsible for that. Normally, the user has the responsibility of using the scanner when the relevant textbox has the focus.

> How do I know when the entire barcode has been scanned?

- The scanner should take care of that. It should transmit its data only when it senses a complete barcode has been scanned.

> How to get barcode Scannar input in my application?

- The same way you would get data typed from a keyboard in your application. You can use stdin (System.in in Java). If you are using a GUI, you can use a text field, text box, text edit pane, etc.

So, the short answer is this: Write the application as if you didn't have a barcode scanner.

This applies regardless of the language you use to code your application.